# After PCA, will the points on the convex hull still be on the hull in the low-dimension space?

Tags: convex-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis, convex-hulls

I have thousands of spectral reflectance data with dimension of 31, in order to reduce the data size to operate some clustering algorithms, I have to use PCA to reduce the dimension of spectral reflectance matrix. So my question is, if some points in the 31-dimension hyperspace is the vertices of the convex hull, will these points still be the vertices in the low-dimension hyperspace after PCA?
My intuitive answer is YES, but is there any paper gave the proof?
Many thanks.

Comment: Some points of the convex hull will become interior points after the linear transformation (try with a sphere in 3d projected in 2d). But transforming only the points of the convex hull is enough for defIning the convex hull of the transformed points.